# Feedback form slideIn from the bottom with position:absolute

Tags: jquery, css

I want to open a feedback form from the bottom of the page with an 'absolute' position.

Problem is that the div goes under the visible page and creates a scroll bar.
Is there a way to make it do the same without it going under the screen border?

Also, once the feedback is clicked, it should change to 'close' in order to close it and restart it from the beginning.

Here is my Code :

```
 <div id="feedback">
    <div id="feedback_slide">Feedback</div>
    <div id="contents">
content here       
    </div>
</div>

   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#feedback').click(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ bottom: 0 }, 350);
    });

    //change 'feedback' to 'close'

    $('#feedback_slide').click(function(){
        $('#feedback').stop().animate({ bottom: -280 }, 350);
    });
});
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/)

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much easier way to do this.

### 1. Your position should be "fixed", not "absolute"

When you position something absolutely, it actually places it in the page at that point, which is not what you want. Position it fixed and it will scroll with the page.

### 2. Use `.toggleClass()`

to handle open and closed styles, and then just use transition-durations to move the feedback widget:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#feedback').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#feedback {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -280px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.35s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.35s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.35s;
    transition-duration: 0.35s;
}

#feedback.open
{
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/1/)

---

Note that this will toggle it when any part of `#feedback` is clicked.

If you only want `#feedback_slide` to trigger the event, bind it there and call `.parent("#feedback").toggleClass()` instead:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/2/)

---

### Edit:

If you want to change the text from feedback to close based on the parent's current class, you can perform a ternary check inside a `.html()` function like so:

```
$(this).html(($(this).parent("#feedback").hasClass("open") ? "Feedback" : "Close")).parent("#feedback").toggleClass("open");
```

I'll break it up into its components here:

```
$(this).html(
    ($(this).parent("#feedback").hasClass("open") ? "Feedback" : "Close")
).parent("#feedback").toggleClass("open");
```

So if the parent `#feedback` has the class `.open`, it will change the text to "Feedback", but if not, it will change it to "Close".

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/4/)

---

### Edit:

In case anyone looks at this for reference, here is the final fiddle, implemented with a height that increases when the feedback is clicked and hidden overflow:

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/11/)

Comment: Your second jsfiddle is what I wanted! problem is, I do need it to be absolute beacuase I have a footer that will move if the page stretches out with lots of content so i need the feedback bar to move with it and be hidden like here http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/3/ also, how can i change the 'feedback' word to 'close' when it is open?

Comment: @Gadgetster To change feedback to close, see my edit

Comment: @Gadgetster So you want the feedback button to stick to the top of the footer?

Comment: yes exactly! i want it to stick to the top of the footer. and since the footer is absolute, the feedback button can't be fixed other wise it will not follow the footer as it moves

Comment: @Gadgetster Are you looking for something more [**like this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/6/)

Comment: not exactly. the footer should be as high as it was and nothing show make the page scroll. the idea is that when content is added to the point that it starts pushing the footer down the page, the feedback button should stay at the same spot on top of the footer. right now what i have is this: http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/8/ how can i remove that whole feedback part under the footer so the scrollbar goes away?

Comment: any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Gadgetster you can only do that by changing the height of the feedback element [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/9/)

Comment: that only works if there is nothing inside the feedback contents div. here is the problem that i have http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/10/

Comment: @Gadgetster Oops forgot the overflow:hidden. [**How's this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/eTNq6/11/)

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted! thank you so much for your help